# WURFL with Zend Framework ignoring cache directory configuration

Tags: zend-framework, wurfl

I'm following the tutorial on setting up WURFL with Zend Framework to enable easy mobile browser detection.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.user-agent.html#zend.http.user-agent.quick-start

I have got it setup to the point where it can detect a desktop browser and give me all the details and features of that browser, but when I try to access the website using an iPhone (mobile safari) it throws an error when trying to write to the cache directory.

Here's what I'm seeing in my error logs:

```
2011-06-08T22:32:34-07:00 ERR (3): The file cache directory does not exist and could not be created. Please make sure the cache directory is writeable: /var/tmp
```

However in my configuration at /application/configs/wurfl-config.php I have set the cache directory to the following:

```
<?php
$resourcesDir            = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../data/wurfl/';

$wurfl['main-file']      = $resourcesDir  . 'wurfl-2.0.27.zip';
$wurfl['patches']        = array($resourcesDir . 'web_browsers_patch.xml');

$persistence['provider'] = 'file';
$persistence['dir']      = $resourcesDir . '/cache/';

$cache['provider']       = null;

$configuration['wurfl']       = $wurfl;
$configuration['persistence'] = $persistence;
$configuration['cache']       = $cache;
```

I've also ensured it is writable by the server, but wurfl seems to think my cache directory is still /var/tmp

How can I get wurfl to observe my cache directory setting?

**Notes**: The tutorial uses wurfl-1.1 as the example, I have only been able to find wurfl-1.3 on sourceforge. This may be an issue.

**Notes**: I have these lines in my application.ini file:

```
; WURFL
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_api_version = "1.1"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_lib_dir = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/wurfl-php-1.3.0/WURFL/"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_file = APPLICATION_PATH "/configs/wurfl-config.php"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is the correct way to fix it, but for me the issue was solved by adding an extra .dir after the persistence.dir key (using WURFL 1.3.0):

In application.ini: (I don't use the php config file as I prefer not to mix in php code if I can use .ini directives)

```
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_array.persistence.dir.dir  = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/wurfl/cache/"
```

So my complete config for WURFL looks like this in Zend's application.ini:

```
; Mobile device detection
resources.useragent.storage.adapter             = "Session"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_api_version  = "1.1"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_lib_dir      = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/WURFL/"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_array.wurfl.main-file      = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/wurfl/wurfl.xml"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_array.wurfl.patches[]      = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/wurfl/web_browsers_patch.xml"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_array.persistence.provider = "file"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_array.persistence.dir.dir  = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/wurfl/cache/"
```

perhaps a bug in the framework regarding how it reads the config array it's being passed?

Comment: Ok, I didn't even know all that was possible from within the .ini file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just resolved the problem ;)

remove the `[]` from the code line below:

```
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_array.wurfl.patches[]      = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/wurfl/web_browsers_patch.xml"
```

transform it to:

```
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_array.wurfl.patches = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/wurfl/web_browsers_patch.xml"
```

Comment: Pity that your `patches[]` line isn't in your original question -- perhaps if the whole config file had been included, someone might have spotted your problem sooner. Also, [Jens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299986/wurfl-with-zend-framework-ignoring-cache-directory-configuration/6423588#6423588) has a config with the `patches[]`, so further study would be worthwhile in any event.

Comment: I never had a patches[] line in my original config, but after using Jens answer and this one I now have this part of it working. Thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the format of the parameters has changed in version 1.3 - the WURFL docs [here](http://www.scientiamobile.com/api-doc/php/WURFL_Configuration/WURFL_Configuration_ArrayConfig.html) have the details and an example file.

So for the original question, the $persistence['dir'] line needs to be changed to:

```
$persistence['params']   = array(
    'dir' => $resourcesDir . '/cache/'
);
```

Comment: Ah, that's where the docs are! Thank you for answering my initial question, as above I've gone with the .ini way of doing things but this answer is very helpful +1 from me!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem using Wurfl 1.3.1 and reading this:

http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/nphp/

Answer (score 1):

With regards to [Jens Wegar's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6423588/1439760), there is a bug-fix request in to fix this as it's not clear.

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12284

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the UserAgent resource to use the settings you are showing here?

You have to add resource.useragent.wurfl_* entries into your application.ini file.

Here is a sample:

```
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_api_version = "1.1"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_lib_dir = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/WURFL/"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_file = APPLICATION_PATH "/configs/wurfl-config.php"
```

Comment: Yep, I've added these similar lines to the application.ini file: ; WURFL
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_api_version = "1.1"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_lib_dir = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/wurfl-php-1.3.0/WURFL/"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_file = APPLICATION_PATH "/configs/wurfl-config.php"